# What causes this list to be passed by reference when called one way, but by value another?

Tags: c#

I was making a simple test for running a validation method and came across this strange situation.

```
public IEnumerable<int> ints (List<int> l)
{
 if(false)yield return 6;
 l.Add(4);
}


void Main()
{
 var a = new List<int>();
 var b = new List<int>();
 for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ){
  a.Add(i);
  b.Add(i);
 }
 a.AddRange(ints(a));
 ints(b);
 Console.WriteLine(a);
 Console.WriteLine(b);
}
```

Once this code runs, `a` will contain `[0,1,2,3,4]`. However, `b` will contain `[0,1,2,3]`. Why did calling the method as an argument in `AddRange` allow the list to be passed by reference? Or if that didn't happen, what did?

Comment: Seems like it's the `AddRange` call itself that caused the additional entry in `a`, not the call to `ints()`.  Though I can't quite follow this code - for example, is there a missing return statement (or a warning about dead code) in the `ints()` method?

Comment: BTW, I think a clearer way to write your `ints()` would be: `l.Add(4); yield break;`.

Comment: @svick - I haven't used `yield` much so I just wrote part of this to see how the return behavior was acting and came across this situation. I wouldn't use code like this in production it just highlighted the issue :). To satisfy curiosity this is what the real code is: `public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {DateTime date = this.FirstDate;foreach (var step in Sequence(this.FinalStep, this.TopSteps, this.BottomSteps)){if (date < step.DateChosen){yield return new ValidationResult("Dates Not In Chronological Order");}date = step.DateChosen;}}`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`ints(b)` call does not enumerate `IEnumerable`, so code never reaches `l.Add(4)` line, unlike in `AddRange` case which enumerates all items to add them to the list.

To see it called for `b` case enumerate result manually:

```
ints(b).ToList();
```

`IEnumerable<T>` implemented via functions are not executing body of the function before enumeration starts - the code is actually transformed by compiler into class with states  to support true lazy evaluation of enumerable (details can be found in multiple articles, i.e. [Iterator Pattern demystified](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/359873/Csharp-Iterator-Pattern-demystified) - link provided by Tim Schmelter).

Comment: this may be noted like a bug: because the behavior of the method *should* not be affected by the way it was called. Especially if we are talking about general purpose API.

Comment: @Tigran `ints` returns a IEnumerable which has a well defined behavior, if you **do not** enumerate the enumerable the expected behavior is that **the enumerable is never executed**. That act of delayed execution is the entire basis that LINQ is built upon for things like Linq2Sql.

Comment: @Tigran Except that there is no "depending on how `ints()` was called". What the method is supposed to do and does is construct and return a synthetised class implementing `IEnumerable<int>` that, **when enumerated**, yields the values as you'd expect from the method body. There's no reason for the compiler to guarantee any behaviour analogous to a regular method when nothing gets yielded since it isn't one.

Comment: This is not a bug, it is entirely by design. It may be unexpected if you don't know about it, but to be a bug, it has to be unexpected to for the people that designed and wrote this compiler as well, which it is not.

Comment: @Tigran Basically, your "expectation" seems to be that the synthetised class attempt to compute the first value to be yielded early. The language designers chose to only attempt to compute values the moment they're needed. This is more or less an arbitrary design choice but the latter one makes a whole lot more sense in the context of delayed execution.

Comment: @millimoose: ok, but the point is that in this concrete code the enumeration is never enumerated, caused by unreachable code. That means that we have never enumeration acting, but what we have is a *declaaration* of enumeration. And only declaration already changes the behavior. Isn't it?

Comment: @Tigran the fact of it being unreachable does not change the result, change the code to `{ bool temp = true;
 if(temp){ temp = false; yield return 6;}
 l.Add(4);
}` and you still get the same behavior.

Comment: @Tigran I believe the unreachable code is in the code sample on purpose to demonstrate the seemingly weird behaviour of the compiler here. (The larger bug would be having any side effects at all in an iterator method, which I'd argue is more likely to be a bad idea than not.)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: great! That is a point. Move you yield *inside* unreachable code, or leave it out, it's the same!. that is *exact* point. So only the **presence**  of yield already affects the behavior of the method.

Comment: `ints(b);` is like `Enumerable.Range(1,999999999);`, it does nothing, whereas `a.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1,999999999))` enumerates the sequence in `AddRange`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: correct. but the "stuff" that is going to *actually run enumeration* (yield) is inside unreachable code, so it **is not** and **will not** ever executed, but it *by the way*  makes method behave in different ways: either caller access enumeration or not. That is a point.

Comment: @Tigran You do realise that the method can't have a different return type based on whether some code is unreachable (dynamically or statically) or not? Seriously, how would you fix this "bug" without making half of the remainder of C# bizarre?

Comment: @Tigran [Here is a simple program](http://ideone.com/rbZM6g) that demonstrates that the code is only run if the enumerator is enumerated. It has ***nothing*** to do with unreachable code.

Comment: @Tigran Basically, it seems you're "proposing" the whole model of how iterators work be changed. I'd like to at least roughly know what this new model you have in mind would look like and how it'd fit into the context of a statically typed compiled language.

Comment: @millimoose: I don't propose anything. But the point you mantioned that the *retun type is different* was completely missed by me. Absolutely missed that point. You're right, my fault.

Comment: @Tigran I guess that's something I should've said more explicitly, but I did allude to that in my very first comment. The compiler has no choice but to compile a method *wildly* differently based on whether or not it sees a `yield return`, statically, reachable or not. (Not like the compiler can use anything but static information here.) That the required return type is different is just a small detail.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: again my point was, just that that either the code unreachable or not the bahaviour is the same. but I completely missed the point about that *return type actually mutates* based on how the function used. I was wrong, nothing to say.

Comment: @millimoose: agree. The fact that compiler declares it even if it unreachable is perfectly fine (compiler it does with local function variables too, it's extremely hard, if not impossible, to make perfectly correct static analysis of the code and compute all possible conditions of execution). My point was, that it should not affect *the behavior of the method based on how its called by caller*. but, again, I completely missed the point about mutation of returned value.